# how can I find the top100 facebook pages with the most likes?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I find the top 100 facebook pages with the most likes?  What kind of granular options would I have with this?  For example, would it be possible to qualify my query for 100 musicians, top 100 athletes, top 100 actors, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can only search for Pages by name and location, there is no way to filter by number of likes.

Search API in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search